# Editing JsonArray using Jackson library

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

My Json is like this

```
{
  "A1":"1234",
  "A2": "123",   
  "A3": "???",
  "A4": "object, may not be populated.",
  "A5": { },
  "A6": { },
  "A7":{
    "B1": ["100"],
    "B2": ["C"],
    "B3": ["O", "A"]
},
  "A8":{
      "B4":["D1"],
      "B5":["D2"],
      "B6":["D3"],
      "B7":["D4"],
      "B8":["D5"],
      "B9":["D6"],
      "B10":["123"]
    }
  "ignoreThisField": "it is useless"
}
```

I am using Jackson library. I want to edit let's say element B4, which is inside A8 and it is of array type.
 I tried below code

```
    byte[] jsonData = readJson(JsonFilePath);

    // Convert json String to object

    POJOClass pojo= getValue(jsonData, POJO.class);

    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, true);

    JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonData);
    // ((ObjectNode) rootNode).put("B4", "A" + "Somedata");
```

But it gives me output as

```
"B4":"[Somedata]"
```

instead of

```
"B4":["Somedata"]
```

which results in unexpected result. 

B4 node contains list of data. How can we edit a node which is type array.
If we can not achieve this using jackson then is there any other library which can solve the problem?

 I tried below links 

[Modify JsonNode of unknown JSON dynamically in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41360172/modify-jsonnode-of-unknown-json-dynamically-in-java) and [How to retrieve and update json array element without traversing entire json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569155/how-to-retrieve-and-update-json-array-element-without-traversing-entire-json)
 but could not achieve much out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am not wrong you want to modify the `B4` object present in the JSON data. To correctly do it you should use the below code.

```
        JsonNode node = rootNode.get("A8");
        List<String>list = new ArrayList<String>();//create a ArrayList
        list.add("Anything"); //add data to arraylist 
        ArrayNode arrayNode = ((ObjectNode)node).putArray("B4"); //add the arraydata into the JSONData
        for (String item : list) { //this loop will add the arrayelements one by one.
            arrayNode.add(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you not using jackson lib fully.

```
<YOur pojo object> mypojo =objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, <yourpojo.class>);
```

now you can just use getter setter

Comment: I am doing that and using setter method I tried to set the value of particular node but it did not workout

Comment: i am really interested to know about same ? will you mind to share your pojo ? you can surely use Node but there are easy ways to go such.